# Exporting Mapinfo Custom Shortcuts

Tags: mapinfo

So I have spend quite a bit of time reassigning F1 to F12 to mapinfo tools that suits our work line using **Command Editor**. Now I need to do same for couple of other computers. I was wondering if I can easily export this shortcut settings to another computer.

Comment: Hi @user69743 , welcome to the site! If you take a look at the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) you'll note it asks to please detail what you have already tried. Please update the question to add some more detail of what you've done.

Comment: Hi @om_henners, Thank you for your suggestion about posting. I will surely be detailed next time. For now I have Peter has kindly offered answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MapInfo Pro 15.2 the key gestures are stored in the Command.xml file that you can find in the application data folder:

%appdata%\MapInfo\MapInfo\Professional\1520

Each MapInfo Pro command is represented with most of its attributes as you can see here:

```
<MapInfoProCommand MenuId="109" Name="SaveCurrentWorkspace">
    <DisplayText>Save Workspace</DisplayText>
    <MenuItemText>Save Workspace</MenuItemText>
    <MenuItemToggleText>Save Workspace</MenuItemToggleText>
    <KeyGesture>Ctrl+Shift+S</KeyGesture>
    <ToolTipDescription>Save Current Workspace (Ctrl+Shift+S)</ToolTipDescription>
    <ToolTipText>Save current session as a named configuration.</ToolTipText>
    <ToolTipDisabledText>This command is disabled. It should always be enabled.</ToolTipDisabledText>
    <SmallIcon>pack://application:,,,/MapInfo.StyleResources;component/Images/Application/saveWorkspace_16x16.png</SmallIcon>
    <LargeIcon>pack://application:,,,/MapInfo.StyleResources;component/Images/Application/saveWorkspace_32x32.png</LargeIcon>
</MapInfoProCommand>
```

You can copy this file to another pc where MapInfo Pro is installed and so share the key gestures.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. I have already recieved lots of help from you in mapinfo group and now in stackexchange, its great!! Thank you.